# Spark 2.2.1 on One PC spark.master local[*] vs spark://192.168.1.5:7077

Tags: java, apache-spark, windows-7

I have standalone Windows 7 PC with Spark 2.2.1.
Write extra simple Java application for reading json (from people.json)
When I execute (run from eclipse) with spark.master=local[*] it's everything well,

```
Dataset<Row> df = spark.read().option("header","false").json(jsonPath);
 df.printSchema();
 df.show();
```

it read json and output correct.

But when I change spark.master=spark://192.168.1.5:7077 it fails with errors like:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang3/time/FastDateParser$2
```

with

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
<version>3.5</version>
```

and errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern component: XXX
at org.apache.commons.lang3.time.FastDateFormat.parsePattern(FastDateFormat.java:577)
```

with

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
<version>3.1</version>
```

Java:

```
C:\Users\gdev>java -version 
java version "1.8.0_161"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_161-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.161-b12, mixed mode)
```

and this jre in eclipse.

What's wrong and what I do incorrect?
Thanks.

Comment: spark://192.168.1.5:7077
Is a local master and hava slave connected to it. It's correctly shown in WebUI. And I can see my application run history.

Answer (score 0):

```
I struggle with this problem. There is problem with pattern of one of column data. I stuck with same problem and got solution.
Please try to run following code. It will work for me.

var df = session.read.format("csv")
          .option("header", true)
          .option("inferSchema", true)
          .option("timestampFormat", "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss ZZ")
          .load("file:///home/rajeev/abc.csv")
```